# Help converting a bitmap to a png in memory using libpng

Tags: c, bitmap, libpng

Basically I would like to convert a bitmap to a png using libpng but rather than outputting it to a FILE* I would like to output it to a char*. I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821806/how-to-encode-png-to-buffer-using-libpng) related post but I don't see where the bitmap data is actually used. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `png_set_write_fn` function to redirect writes to your own function; this function, which you need to write, can store the output in any way you want.

See the documentation at http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-manual.txt

Comment: Great, thanks for the help. I finally solved it here is my solution in case anyone else is as much of a noob as me:

first set the your row_pointers so each row_pointer points to a row in your bitmap. (row_pointers[i] = bitmap[i*bitmap_width*3], 3 if it's an RGB bitmap).

Then set the rows:
png_set_rows( png_ptr, info_ptr, row_pointers );

Then call:
png_set_write_fn( ... )

And finally call your write_fn by calling:
png_write_png( ... )