# How to correctly include/install libpng?

Tags: c++, png, libpng

I'm trying to use [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) into my project. I've installed it, by downloading the setup of the **Complete package, except sources** from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libpng.htm) and executing that `.exe` installation file.

But when I include it using

```
#include <png.h>
```

or

```
#pragma comment(lib, "png.h")
```

this wouldn't work. How do I please to correctly install it to be able to include it?

Comment: What is the OS and IDE you're using..?

Comment: @Diunuge, Windows 7 SP1 and Visual Studio Ultimate 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the library path to the system environment variable. You can modify the project configurations by adding the c++ directories to the library include path and lib path.

Configurations depends on the IDE you're using..

For VS;
In VS project setting; set these variables.
C/C++ general --> Additional include directories; libpng \include path
Linker --> General --> Additional library directories; libpng \lib path

Also, add the /bin path to the Windows System 'path' Environment variable.

Comment: Would you please more detail ? What to add exactly to the system environment variable? And, how to modify the prject config?

Comment: In fact, does libpng allows convsion from bitmap to png? xD

Comment: As I remember, yes. refere http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739667/help-converting-a-bitmap-to-a-png-in-memory-using-libpng

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler can't find the libpng location on the system.
Check the environment variables and Project configurations.

Comment: Would you please more detail ? What to add exactly to the system environment variable? And, how to modify the prject config?

Comment: You have to add the libpng /bin path to the system environment variable.